# How to extract weights and biases in h2o model if export_weights_and_bias argument was set to FALSE?

Tags: deep-learning, pojo, h2o, checkpoint

I have an h2o deeplearning model, "model1", that generalizes very well. Unfortunately, I forgot to set export weights and biases = `TRUE` when building the model.

I've tried to retrain numerous models with all the exact parameters, seed, and dataset as in the original model1 plus added set export weights and biases to true.

Unfortunately **none** of these new models generalize well at all. In fact they all fail miserably to generalize - although all models train, validate, cross-validate and test very well. I've even tried checkpointing the original model1 so I can add the export weights and biases argument = `TRUE`. However, because I did not use Modulo CV, I'm unable to checkpoint.

Irreproducibility is giving me a huge headache. In order for me to productionalize, I need to somehow extract the weights and biases of this original, working model1 - despite export weights and biases being originally set to `FALSE`.

I've looked at the *mean* weights and biases of model1 and they simply do not match any of mean weights and biases of my retrained models with same parameters, seed, dataset, etc. I'm uncertain if mean weights and biases can be used somehow to force reproducibility.

I've read that downloading model1 to POJO `may` allow access to the weights and biases, but I'm uncertain about this, I don't know java and I don't see any example java code to help me along.

Any suggestions or other possible solutions/workarounds?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I partially resolved this on my own: after downloading model to POJO, I opened up the file with a text editor based on Darren Cook's suggestion (thank you), and I think I can see all the weights and biases here.

I'm not certain however b/c I'm unfamiliar with the POJO format.